# Почему при создание Scrapy проекта в Docker контейнере она прячется в директории python3?

Tags: docker

При создании Scrapy проекта в Docker контейнере, она создается в директории '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/templates/project'

Как сделать чтобы проект и сам паук создавался в заданной мной директории

Answer (score 0):

Почитай [документацию](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html). Создавай проект  - `scrapy startproject myproject [project_dir]`. Для разработки используй `VOLUME`. В `container` нужно объявить `SCRAPY_PROJECT` или все переменные прописать в `settings` или `scrapy.cfg` в `project root`.